# Getting address from struct mapping

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a struct in a library:

```
// lib
struct Data {
    int256 count;
    mapping(address => int256) indices;
    mapping(int256 => address) items;
}

// Also append function in lib
function append(Data storage self, address addr)
internal
returns (bool) {
    if (addr == ZERO_ADDRESS) {
        return false;
    }

    int256 index = self.indices[addr] - 1;
    if (index >= 0 && index < self.count) {
        return false;
    }

    self.count++;
    self.indices[addr] = self.count;
    self.items[self.count] = addr;
    return true;
}
```

And then another contract that uses this library struct:

```
// Contract.sol
using LibMap for LibMap.Data;
mapping(address => LibMap.Data) public addresses;
```

And then in a function I push to it

```
addresses[msg.sender].append(addr);
```

From the front end with web3 I can do `contract.addresses(msg.sender)` where msg.sender is the address from earlier in the contract that was set and it will return a length/count of how many have been appended. But how would I rather read all the addresses that have been pushed instead of a length/count?

Would I need a function in the contract for this?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to achieve with `addresses[msg.sender].append(addr);` ?

Comment: Its a list of public contract addresses. And I need to access those contract address list for `msg.sender` from the front end

Comment: Have you defined the `append` function somewhere?

Comment: append is in the lib. I updated question above. `items` holds the addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read all the addresses appended to any given `Data`, you will have to do it iteratively.

You could do this on the frontend, by querying the contract for what the value of `addresses[msg.sender].count`, and then loop through and get the value of everything in `addresses[msg.sender].items` one at a time (from `1` to `count`).

The alternative would just be to do the same sort of thing with a function in your contract, loop through and return an array of them.

You can't just return a mapping though.

Comment: Thanks. I added a function in my contract that will pull at index, and on the front end I can iterate through the count.